# Converting a max-min problem to a max problem with a constraint

Tags: matrices, optimization, linear-programming, semidefinite-programming

The objective is to find the greatest lower bound of the variable $\mu$. The lower bound is resulting from the positive-semidefinite (PSD) constraint $$\tilde{\mathbf{T}}:=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 16 \mu -x(2)-4 x(10) & \frac{x(8)}{2}+2 x(11)+x(12) & 8 \mu -x(2)-2 x(10)+x(12) \\
 \frac{x(8)}{2}+2 x(11)+x(12) & 4 \mu -x(2)-2 x(5)-x(8)-2 x(10) & -x(2)+2 x(11)+x(12) \\
 8 \mu -x(2)-2 x(10)+x(12) & -x(2)+2 x(11)+x(12) & 2 (8 \mu -x(2)-2 x(10)+x(12)) \\
\end{array}
\right)\succeq0,$$where $\mathbf{x}$ is a 12-dimensional vector. Now, I optimize over $\mathbf{x}$, when subjected to PSD conditions on 4 matrices $\mathbf{T}_i$ which depend linearly in the components of $\mathbf{x}$, and a set of given constants $\mathit{c}_j$. Symbolically, I write  $\mathbf{T}_i(c_j,\mathbf{x})\succeq0$. 
Thus, the problem is $$\underset{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{T}_{i}\succeq0}{\mathrm{max}}\underset{\tilde{\mathbf{T}}\succeq0}{\mathrm{min}\ \mu}.$$
Does anyone have a idea how the internal minimization problem can be replaced with by additional constraint, say $c(\mu,\mathbf{x})$, for the other one? i.e., to receive $$\underset{\tilde{\mathbf{T}},\mathbf{x},\mathbf{T}_{i}\succeq0,c(\mu,\mathbf{x})=0}{\mathrm{min}\ \mu.}$$

Comment: Here's what I am thinking. $\tilde{T}$ is positive definite if and only if $G\tilde{T}G^T$ is, where $G$ is nonsingular. If you could eliminate $\mu$ from the $(1,3)$ and $(3,1)$ positions, and then diagonally scale so that the coefficient in front of $\mu$ along the diagonal is 1, then $\mu$ will just be the largest eigenvalue of $G\tilde{T}G^T$,  Alas, this doesn't necessarily help, because maximizing the largest eigenvalue of a matrix is non-convex. But it may indicate the fundamental intractability of the problem.

Comment: Hi Michael, I was thinking along that line, and, indeed, I can apply coordinate transformation for which $\mu$ appears only along the diagonal. However, as you already mentioned, I end up with a non-convex problem; actually, a $minimization$ of the smallest eigenvalue, which is a $concave$ function.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right.